# Code coverage is always unknown with Flutter in GitLab

Tags: flutter, testing, gitlab, cicd

I'm using flutter for this project and when I do the tests I can see the coverage but in the gitlab badge I can't see it.

[Gitlab badge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shyrV.png)

here is my cicd:

[cicd with test job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRepP.png)

here is my cicd configuration:

[Test coverage parsing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vE8YK.png)

Here is my badge configuration

[Badge image URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5omE4.png)

In the output of test job this is the result:

[Test job output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyXgW.png)

Can someone help me with this please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a wrong job name inside the badges url:

`![coverage](https://gitlab.example.com/<namespace>/<project>/badges/<branch>/coverage.svg?job=<jobname>)` ->Make sure that  matches the name of the stage inside your pipeline:

```
stages:
  - test
```

A job with the name test would need this url:

`![coverage](https://gitlab.example.com/<namespace>/<project>/badges/<branch>/coverage.svg?job=test)`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your test coverage parsing regular expression to `lines\.*: (\d+.\d+)%` the parenthesis (capture group) are important to know what number to pick up.

Comment: I did it but I got  the same result

Comment: Try running the text against https://regex101.com while copy/pasting your log file in. You might also consider just using `:\s*(\d+\.\d+)%` as a simplified and see if it is the rest of the group. Or `lines.*: (\d+\.\d+)%`.

Comment: **lines.*: (\d+\.\d+)%** works fine in  [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) but I can't see the test coverage in gitlab badge

Comment: Okay, I was playing around a little with it. Make sure you have Analytics turned on for your project settings. You also can't retry a job to test it, you need to run the entire pipeline again for it to pick up the regex settings. The official test is https://rubular.com/ but your regular expressions should be good for that.

Comment: I can't see Analytics in my project but a few weeks ago coverage badge worked fine

Comment: Just tried it without Analytics and it worked, but I still had to run the entire pipeline. Do you see the coverage in the CI/CD job list? https://server/user/project/-/jobs. If you do (like https://gitlab.com/mfgames-cil/mfgames-locking-cil/-/jobs), it would suggest the badge is pointing to the wrong branch. If you don't, then it is the scanning. ('m using `Line coverage: (\d+\.\d+)%` for mine because it's .NET.)

Comment: No, I can't see the coverage in the CI/CD job list